# javascript queryselectorall nodelist select all accept this

Tags: javascript, dom

I can not seem to find how to get this done proper.

```
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');

menu.forEach(item=>{
   item.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      // now I need to select all menu items accept 'this' to remove 'is-active' class.
      document.querySelector(".menu-link").classList.remove("is-active"); // not working
      !this.classList.remove("is-active"); // not working

      this.classList.add("is-active"); // add active class to menu item
   });
});
```

I know I could again loop trough all items then remove for each item the class and last add for 'this', but I think there should be a way to select all but this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over all menu items again - you're already doing `forEach` to add the listeners, so just do that again inside the listener. After that, reference the `item` (the item being iterated over) to add the class. (Using `this` won't work because you're using an arrow function.)

```
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
menuItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menuItems.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove("is-active");
        });
        item.classList.add("is-active");
    });
});
```

Or save the last active one in a variable

```
let lastActive;
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
menuItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        lastActive?.classList.remove("is-active");
        item.classList.add("is-active");
        lastActive = item;
    });
});
```

If you really want to go the comparison route, then

```
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
menuItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menuItems.forEach(innerItem => {
            if (innerItem !== item) {
                innerItem.classList.remove("is-active");
            }
        });
        item.classList.add("is-active");
    });
});
```

or if you must use `this`, don't use an arrow function.

```
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
menuItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        menuItems.forEach(innerItem => {
            if (innerItem !== this) {
                innerItem.classList.remove("is-active");
            }
        });
        this.classList.add("is-active");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, I did a very long while ago make use of !this, I know there is a way somehow to do it. the suggestions you gave I already know, but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: `!this` doesn't really make sense - that'll be equivalent to using `false`